# cURL returns an empty string

Tags: php, curl

I have following code which returns an empty string (in variable $result)

```
$createdURL = "https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/sendsms.jsp?session_id=123&to=92315&text=test&mask=1"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$createdURL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8')) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo var_dump($result);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Whereas when I run the link given in first line in browser address bar it returns following XML.

```
<corpsms>
    <command>Submit_SM</command>
    <data>Error 102</data>
    <response>Error</response>
</corpsms>
```

Please help where am I wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing curl_init()

So use this code and you'll get a response from the API:

```
<?php

$createdURL = "https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/sendsms.jsp?session_id=123&to=92315&text=test&mask=1";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $createdURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8')) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo var_dump($result);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

You should also check whether you need to send the `Content-Tye: text/xml` header and whether you should be using a `POST` or a `GET`.

Comment: $ch = curl_init(); was there but missed while copying.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to space given in parameters of link like below

$createdURL = "https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/sendsms.jsp?session_id=123&to=92315&text=***test and test***&mask=***my mask***";

After removing space it is now giving output, but now need to tackle matter of spaces.

Comment: don't remove the space, urlencode() the variables, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

When `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is set, output is written to STDERR or the file specified using `CURLOPT_STDERR`. The output is very informative.

You can also use tcpdump or wireshark to watch the network traffic.